# How do I get a button click to change two separate TextView fields in my app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Here is my code. I figured out how to make one text field change when the button is clicked, but the minute I try to add another val like this:

```
val tv = findViewById(R.id.questionfield) as TextView
    tv.text = "What is your name?"
```

I get an error that says:
"Conflicting declarations: val tv: Textview, val tv: TextView"

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
        android:text="Avatar Response Field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/welcome" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
/>
<TextView
        android:text="Question Pop Up Field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/questionfield" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497" 
android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" 
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"/>
<Button
        android:text="Click to Ask Alyssa a Question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" 
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"/>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="291dp"
        android:layout_height="261dp" tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/welcome" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView



class MainActivity : Activity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun buttonClick(v: View) {
    val tv = findViewById(R.id.welcome) as TextView
    tv.text = "Hi! I'm Alyssa"
    val tv = findViewById(R.id.questionfield) as TextView
    tv.text = "What is your name?"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable name `tv` is already used in the same scope. You can use a different variable name and try again. For example:

```java
 val tv = findViewById(R.id.welcome) as TextView
    tv.text = "Hi! I'm Alyssa"
    val anotherName = findViewById(R.id.questionfield) as TextView
    anotherName.text = "What is your name?"
```

Comment: I'm new to this and that absolutely worked!! Thank you :)

Comment: you can accept the answer if it worked to help future readers

Comment: I gave it an up vote but because I am new it is just not showing. Is there more I can do? I want to give you your credit :)

Comment: you can not upvote as you don't have enough permission for that. the only thing you can do is to accept the answer by ticking the check button near to the answer